# Add open caret on bootstrap accordion

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion

I am trying to add open caret on accordian using glyphicons bootstrap, i now i can manage easy if there is just link, but the change is that i want full heading to be clickable, here is my code for now

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title"  data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseTwo">
        <a class="accordion-toggle">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseThree">
        <a class="accordion-toggle">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Tcgyx/15/

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
   .panel-heading {
      cursor: pointer;
      position: relative;
   }

a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

span.indicator {
   position: absolute;
   right: 5px;
   top: 15px;
}
```

And a `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom indicator"></span>` inside your `<div class="panel-heading">`

```
$(function(){
    $(".panel-heading")
       .on("click",function(){
           $(".indicator").toggleClass("glyphicon-triangle-bottom glyphicon-triangle-left");
       });
});
```

Clicking on the `.panel-heading` toggles the arrow from down to left.

Comment: It stays on down i need to go on left when is closed?

Comment: Do you want the `span.caret` to toggle from up and down on click?

Comment: I want to be on down when is open and pointing to left when is closed